# Xcode suddenly started saying it is missing two files (including the .app file) and won't build

Tags: xcode

I was working on some changes in one of my .swift files and tried to build the app to confirm they were correct. Suddenly the preview stops working and the app won't build and I get a random number of errors when I try to build it. The failed builds say that basically all the files do not exist. However, if I click down the project file tree only two give the error (project.app and one random.swift). However they DO show the file after I click the okay message.

I am including two photos of the error after one build attempt. I also have an exported error file but it's huge. Also none of the file names are in red.

[image]

[image]

I also get the files do not exist error when I try adding them to any other projects.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Clean build folder
- Deleted and dropped the two files back in
- Deleted and re-added to the sources area under build phases
- Confirmed that using show in finder shows the actual file

Comment: Did you check for Taget Membership, like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48343196/16157878

Comment: Looks like you posted the same picture twice.